# populate text fields in angular js based on datalist value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to populate text box fields based on data list count. If count is 3 , i have to populate 3 textbooks.

```
<datalist id="testList">
    <option ng-repeat="des in DesList" value=" {{des.id}} ({{des.code}})" data-ng-change="addText(des.id)>
</datalist>
```

i try to create script like this.but no luck.

```
 this.addText = function(count) {

    this.arrayText.push(obj);

  }
}
```

Comment: add more information

Comment: where you defined obj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7ym139q9/2/)

Updated code here  [Jsfiddle link updated](https://jsfiddle.net/7ym139q9/5/)

**Js code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.rules = [{
      name: 'rule1',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'rule2',
      id: 2
    }];
    $scope.data = [];
    var dummy = [];

    $scope.addText = function(rule) {

      dummy.push(rule);
      if (dummy.length > 2) {
        $scope.data = angular.copy(dummy);
        $scope.one = $scope.data[0];
        $scope.two = $scope.data[1];
        $scope.three = $scope.data[2];
      }
    }
  });
```

**HTML code**

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
      <select ng-options='item.name as item.name for item in rules' ng-model='rule' ng-change='addText(rule)'>

      </select>
      <hr> Length: {{data.length}}
      <hr>
      <div ng-if='data.length > 2'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='one'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='two'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='three'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As per your problem i build this but you can extend this

Comment: some part of your answer is write. how can i remove one text box if selected index is 2 . please help

Comment: But how can i add text boxes  equal to selected value .  if selected value is 1, i want to show 1 text box . if selected value 4, i want to show 4 text boxes . please help

Comment: If selected value change to 3 to 1 , three text boxes already there. i want only one text box if select 1.please help